# vb script - if i run iexplore.exe through c:\ how can i navigate the browser window further

Tags: browser, vbscript, automation

If I use

```vb
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

To open a URL I can use the following

```
ie.Navigate "http://google.com"
```

But I cant go for this option because, "InternetExplorer.Application" opens 64-bit IE browser. I need 32-bit IE browser to work. So I used the following

```
set Objshell=CreateObject("WScript.shell")  
return=Objshell.run ("""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe""" & "www.google.com")
```

So in this case I don't know how to navigate or to use `getElements()` for that opened browser window.

Please let me know how to handle this!

Answer (score 1):

```
  Option Explicit 

 Main() 

 Sub Main() 
     Force32bit() 
     Dim objExplorer : Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
     Dim i 

i = true 
do while i = true 
     objExplorer.Navigate "www.google.com" 
     objExplorer.ToolBar = 1 
     objExplorer.StatusBar = 1 
     objExplorer.Width = 800 
     objExplorer.Height = 800 
     objExplorer.Left = 1 
     objExplorer.Top = 1 
     objExplorer.Visible = 1 
     WScript.Sleep 6000 
     objExplorer.Navigate "www.yahoo.com" 
wscript.sleep 6000 
loop 

 End Sub 

 Sub Force32bit() 
     If InStr(UCase(WScript.FullName), "SYSTEM32") > 0 and CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FolderExists("C:\Windows\SysWOW64") Then 
         Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
         objShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" 
         objShell.Run "wscript.exe " & Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34), 1, False 
     End If 
 End Sub
```

Find the solution [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Launching-IE-in-32-bit-mode-from-VBS-script-m80179-p2.aspx)

Comment: If i use Objshell=CreateObject("WScript.shell")
return=Objshell.run ("""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe""" & "www.google.com") how can i deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Shell
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "iexplore.exe www.google.com"
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you go back to your original code and simply modify the instantiation line to the following:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application.1")
```

That should be enough to force a 32-bit instance of the IE application object.

If you still want to go with the shell route, remember that you want to launch the iEXPLORE.EXE from the *Programs (x86)* folder.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```